# Prove vector norm squared identity

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $a$ and $b$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\gamma \in [0,1)$. I would like to prove the following identity:
$$
\|a+b\|^2_2 - \gamma \|a\|^2_2 = (1-\gamma)\left\| a + \frac{1}{1-\gamma}b \right\|^2_2 - \frac{\gamma}{1 - \gamma}\|b\|^2_2.
$$

I tried to use the indentity $\|a+b\|^2_2 + \|a-b\|^2_2 = 2\|a\|^2_2 + 2\|b\|^2_2$ as a starting point, but was not able to make much progress.

Comment: Try expanding norm suqares using inner products e.g:
$||a + b|| ^ 2 = ||a|| ^ 2 + ||b|| ^ 2 + 2 <a, b>$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from the RHS : $\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\|#1\right\|}\newcommand{\scal}[2]{\left\langle#1,#2\right\rangle}$
\begin{align}
(1-\gamma)\norm{a+\frac{1}{1-\gamma}b}^2 - \frac{\gamma}{1-\gamma}\norm{b}^2 &= (1-\gamma)\|a\|^2+2\scal ab + \frac{1}{1-\gamma}\norm{b}^2 - \frac{\gamma}{1-\gamma}\norm b^2 \\
&= \| a\|^2  +2\scal ab + \norm b^2 - \gamma \|a\|^2 \\
&= \norm{a+b}^2 -\gamma \norm{a}^2
\end{align}